# What does this stylized P next to Roblox usernames mean?

Tags: roblox

While playing Roblox my son and I started to notice the symbol below associated with some users names:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out or locate information on what it means.

Even weirder:  When I tried to copy it off the webpage the symbol won't highlight as text or a graphic, my HTML isn't good enough to locate the element.  I was only able to copy it using print screen, and even then a reverse image search came up with nothing related.

Can anyone let us know what this symbol indicates?  We're really curious.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol appears to indicate that the user has Roblox Premium, which is a membership club that includes a Robux stipend and access to our trading and sales features, where you can earn even more Robux through the Roblox Developer program. Currently, it is not available for all users and is in testing. 
https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024256251-Premium-Membership

Comment: If you're going to copy-paste paragraphs of text, can you please style them as quoted text in addition to the attribution?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the new symbol for the new version of what used to be called "Builder's Club", i.e. where you pay a monthly/yearly fee in return for a regular stipend of Robux plus access to premium features. A few months back (September 2019), they changed the name of the program to Roblox Premium, and started paying out the stipend monthly instead of daily. I've only noticed the new symbol next to names in the last day or so (December 2019).